# Is there a formula in excel or VBA to count groups of values? For instance if I had a column with the an "X" in groups of 1, 2, 3 or 4

Tags: worksheet-function, vba

IF column B, 8 rows had xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxx xx xxx. I need to find how many groups of two X, three x and four x. The result of the above would be xx = 4, xxx = 2 and 4 = 2. I've tried VBA but the count is never correct.

[Here is an image of the H column with the word "TRUE". I am trying to count how many time they are consecutive twice, three time or four up to six consecutive "True"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqJJf.png)

Comment: Why didn't you post your faulty VBA code? It can't be that long when done properly.

Comment: For i = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If IsEmpty(Range("H" & i).Value) = True Then
Trucount = 0
 Else
       If Range("H" & i) = Range("H" & i + 1) Then
       Trucount = Trucount + 1
       If IsEmpty(Range("H" & i).Value) = True Then
       GoTo TestThree
       Else
       End If
       If Trucount = 2 Then trucounttwo = trucounttwo + 1
  
   End If
    
        End If
Next i
Range("N3").Value = trucounttwo

Comment: The word can be between blanks in Column H .                                                          For i = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If IsEmpty(Range("H" & i).Value) = True Then
Trucount = 0
 Else
       If Range("H" & i) = Range("H" & i + 1) Then
       Trucount = Trucount + 1
       If IsEmpty(Range("H" & i).Value) = True Then
       GoTo TestThree
       Else
       End If
       If Trucount = 2 Then trucounttwo = trucounttwo + 1
  
   End If
    
        End If
Next i
Range("N3").Value = trucounttwo

Comment: Al, putting the code into your question would make it readible. 
"IF column B, 8 rows had xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxx xx xxx." A sentence has to contain a verb. Apart from that "8 rows had xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxx xx xxx." is nothing I would understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range
Dim ocr1, ocr2, ocr3, ocr4, ocr5, ocr6, ocr7

Set rg = Range("H1")
If rg = "" Then Set rg = rg.End(xlDown)

    Do
        If rg.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            Select Case Range(rg, rg.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                Case 2: ocr2 = ocr2 + 1
                Case 3: ocr3 = ocr3 + 1
                Case 4: ocr4 = ocr4 + 1
                Case 5: ocr5 = ocr5 + 1
                Case 6: ocr6 = ocr6 + 1
                Case 7: ocr7 = ocr7 + 1
            End Select
            Set rg = rg.End(xlDown).End(xlDown)
        Else
            ocr1 = ocr1 + 1
            Set rg = rg.End(xlDown)
        End If
    Loop Until rg.Row = Rows.Count

Debug.Print "no consecutive occurence = " & ocr1
Debug.Print "two consecutive occurence = " & ocr2
Debug.Print "three consecutive occurence = " & ocr3
Debug.Print "four consecutive occurence = " & ocr4
Debug.Print "five consecutive occurence = " & ocr5
Debug.Print "six consecutive occurence = " & ocr6
Debug.Print "seven consecutive occurence = " & ocr7

End Sub
```

The goal is to get how many times it occur for each consecutive rows with a value.

the rg variable is the cell to start.
If the rg is empty then it do end(xldown) and set this cell as the rg.

Then it do the loop

First it check if the cell below the rg is empty then it means there is no consecutive occurence, so it add 1 to the ocr1 variable then set the rg to the next rg with value

If the cell below the rg is not empty, then it use a case on how many rows is the range with consecutive occurence. Each is assign to each own variable.

If there are two consecutive rows with value, then it add 1 to the ocr2.
If there are three consecutive rows with value, then it add 1 to the ocr3.
and so on. 
Then it set the rg to the next rg with value

Since I don't how many consecutive rows with value at max, I just made it to 7. If you know there is a limit (means, you know that the consecutive rows with value won't exceed from 4) then just delete the case 5 to case 7.

Run the sub where the sheet as seen in your picture is active
Again, that if I understand you correctly.